# Probability of non-normalizable states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability, normalization

In the book Quantum Field Theory by Jakob Schwichtenberg, he is discussing about non-normalizable states in chapter 8. If you compute the normalization in $(8.67)$ you just get infinity. He said one way out of this is to just assume a finite volume $V$ so that the normalization is now a finite $V$ in $(8.68)$.

The part I'm not so sure how to think about is $(8.69)$, where you can compute probabilities of non-normalizable states only if you consider *probability ratios*. Can anyone give me an example where a non-normalizable state $\lvert i \rangle$ time evolves to a non-normalizable state $\lvert f \rangle$ through $U$ and that in the end there is a volume $V$ factor that comes out to cancel $\langle i \lvert i \rangle$ and $\langle f \lvert f \rangle$ which are just equal to $V$?

[image]

**Update 1.**

First, let $\vert f \rangle = \vert \vec{k} \rangle$ and $\vert i \rangle = \vert \vec{q} \rangle$

$$\langle \vec{k} \vert \vec{k} \rangle = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x \langle \vec{k} \vert \vec{x} \rangle \langle \vec{x} \vert \vec{k} \rangle = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x e^{-i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} = L^3 = V.$$

Similar computations are done for $\langle \vec{q} \vert \vec{q} \rangle$.

For $|\langle f \vert \mathrm{U} \vert i \rangle|^2 = |\langle \vec{k} \vert \mathrm{U} \vert \vec{q} \rangle|^2 = \langle \vec{k} \vert \mathrm{U} \vert \vec{q} \rangle \langle \vec{q} \vert \mathrm{U}^* \vert \vec{k} \rangle$,

$\langle \vec{k} \vert \mathrm{U} \vert \vec{q} \rangle = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x \langle \vec{k} \vert \vec{x} \rangle \langle \vec{x} \vert \mathrm{U} \vert \vec{q} \rangle = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x \langle \vec{k} \vert \vec{x} \rangle \langle \vec{x} \vert e^{-i H t} \vert \vec{q} \rangle =\\
= \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x e^{-i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} e^{-i \omega t} e^{i \vec{q} \cdot \vec{x}} = e^{-i \omega t} 
 \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x e^{i (\vec{q}-\vec{k}) \cdot \vec{x}}.$

$\langle \vec{q} \vert \mathrm{U}^* \vert \vec{k} \rangle = e^{i \omega t} 
 \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x e^{i (\vec{k}-\vec{q}) \cdot \vec{x}}.$

$\lim_{L \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \lim_{\vec{q} \rightarrow \vec{k}} \frac{\langle \vec{k} \vert \mathrm{U} \vert \vec{q} \rangle \langle \vec{q} \vert \mathrm{U}^* \vert \vec{k} \rangle}{ \langle \vec{k} \vert \vec{k} \rangle \langle \vec{q} \vert \vec{q} \rangle}\right] = \frac{(2 \pi)^3 \delta(0) (2 \pi)^3 \delta(0)}{V^2} = \frac{V^2}{V^2}$

where I have applied eq. (8.71).

Thus, $P(i \rightarrow f) = 1$

I’m not sure if my calculation is correct because it assumes $q \rightarrow k$ so that the final state is the same as the initial state even after some time evolution $U$. How about for plane waves that have different initial and final states?

**Update 2.**

Following Ruslan's answer,

$|\langle f \vert \mathrm{U} \vert i \rangle|^2 = \langle f \vert \mathrm{U} \vert i \rangle \langle i \vert \mathrm{U}^* \vert f \rangle$

$\langle f \vert \mathrm{U} \vert i \rangle = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x \langle f \vert \vec{x} \rangle \langle \vec{x} \vert \mathrm{U} \vert i \rangle = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x \langle f \vert \vec{x} \rangle \langle \vec{x} \vert e^{-i H t} \vert i \rangle \\
= \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x e^{-i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} e^{-i \omega t} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} = e^{-i \omega t} 
 \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} d^3x = e^{-i \omega t} V.$

$\langle i \vert \mathrm{U}^* \vert f \rangle = e^{i \omega t} V$

where when we impose the boundary conditions, we get $k\frac{L}{2} = N\pi$. Also, note that $V=L^3$.

Thus, $P(i \rightarrow f) = \frac{|\langle f \vert \mathrm{U} \vert i \rangle|^2}{\langle f \vert f \rangle \langle i \vert i \rangle} = \frac{V^2}{V^2} = 1$

Now, we can take $\lim_{V \rightarrow \infty}$ and still maintain a finite probability, which is 1.

Comment: This may help. [Normalizing the solution to free particle Schrödinger equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165373/37364)

Comment: @mmesser314 That thread explains why plane waves are non-normalizable, it does not help in trying to explain the "probability ratio" stated in my question, i.e. you can only compute probabilities of non-normalizable wave functions through ratios and restricting to finite volume.

Comment: The book is wrong, but it's a very common mistake that disagrees with statements e.g. in Dirac's book etc..., see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/665973/25851) post (and the other answers there to see this in action) where a standard physical interpretation known for nearly a century is quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone give me an example where a non-normalizable state $\lvert i \rangle$ time evolves to a non-normalizable state $\lvert f \rangle$ through $U$ and that in the end there is a volume $V$ factor that comes out to cancel $\langle i \lvert i \rangle$ and $\langle f \lvert f \rangle$ which are just equal to $V$?

What about the simplest example: a plane wave, with free-particle evolution? Take e.g.

\begin{align}
\langle x|i\rangle&=\exp(ikx),\\
\langle x|f\rangle&=\exp\left(ikx-it\frac{k^2}{2m}\right).
\end{align}

These are normalizable if we take a finite interval $L=\frac{2\pi N}k$ with $N\in\mathbb Z$ (assuming Born-von Karman boundary conditions). The norms of both states are $\sqrt L.$ As we take $N\to\infty$, the states become non-normalizable.

With these states we have (taking $\mathcal U=I$ for simplicity):

$$\langle i|\mathcal{U}|f\rangle=\int_0^L \langle i|x\rangle\langle x|f\rangle\,\mathrm{d}x=L\exp\left(-it\frac{k^2}{2m}\right).$$

Then the expression $(8.69)$ in your textbook indeed cancels the $L$, yielding a finite $P(i\to f).$

Comment: Your answer is similar to my update (please see it above), can you check if it is correct? Maybe you can comment more on it.

Comment: @mathemania your calculations don't specify any boundary conditions and thus constraints on $L$, $\vec k$ and $\vec q$. This makes the two final equality signs in the calculation of the matrix element very dubious. Moreover, the $\delta$, which I assume to be the Dirac delta, doesn't make sense if $L<\infty.$

Comment: The point the book is making is to impose a finite volume $V$ then proceed with the usual calculations, then take the probability ratio so that $V$ just cancels out in the end. So I just need to extra impose, for example, periodic boundary conditions? Also, I have added the limit to justify the delta function in my calculations.

Comment: @mathemania you seem to be trying to just formally manipulate the symbols. What you've written, like evaluating Dirac delta at zero and then asserting that it (times a constant) equals $V^2$, doesn't make sense. Try instead doing the actual calculation, finding the value for a finite $V$ (taking the boundary conditions into account!), then taking the limit of $V\to\infty$. Don't forget that boundary conditions also constrain admissible values of $\vec k$ and $\vec q$. (In fact, this calculation is exactly what I did in this answer, just for 1D space.)

Comment: I have added an **Update 2** which is what you are saying. However, you have implicitly assumed that the initial and final states are both described by the momentum $k$? Is that acceptable?

Comment: @mathemania depends on what you want to achieve. My goal was to provide the simplest nontrivial example. You can of course take whatever states you need, just make sure they obey the boundary conditions. Also note that I took a very simple $\mathcal U$, which you might want to change too.

Comment: I guess you set $U = e^{-itk^2/2m}$, while I wrote it as $U = e^{-it\omega}$. So my calculation in **Update 2** is correct, I think doing it using dirac-delta is not such a good idea. Although there might be more ways in making the calculation more general by not assuming the same momentum state for the initial and the final. The probability of 1 makes sense since there is no interaction, so of course the initial and final states have the same momentum state described by $k$.

Comment: @mathemania yeah, you can view it this way, as if I chose the free particle Hamiltonian and identical initial and final states. The Dirac delta shouldn't appear in the calculation at all, since it only appears when you integrate over an infinite interval, which you don't. You can get it in the limit though. Just don't forget about the boundary conditions when you make initial and final state different. In particular, the frequencies of plane waves must be commensurate (this requirement goes away in the limit of $L\to\infty$).

Comment: Yeah, you are correct about the Dirac-delta, the fact that we restrict to a finite volume it shouldn't even appear. Thanks for your insight on this!

Answer (score 0):

In an actual physical measurement one will always have a finite precision, i.e., final volume: e.g., a particle detected in a bubble chamber leaves a trace of finite width. The non-normalizability is important to deal with, in order to be able, e.g., to use Fourier transform and other related mathematical apparatus, but it is just a mathematical artefact.

In a similar way, all particles emitted in experiments are created in a form of *wave packets*, as they are generated with instruments having finite precision and created over finite time interval (certainly shorter than the lifetime of the Universe, and typically shorter than duration of the experiment).

Comment: How does this relate to my question of how to get the probability ratio of non-normalizable states? I know that non-normalizable states are mathematical tools in order to calculate other stuff, e.g. wave packet.

Comment: You are asking where the volume factor comes from - it comes from doing a realistic calculation, which inevitably involves some kind of averaging. Very often one works in the opposite way: assuming periodic boundary conditions, and thus making the states normalizable. Then the volume factor is present from the very beginning, but often cancels out in the end, so that one can pass to the integrals over the "non-normalizable" states.Density-of-states calculations are typically introduced in this way in textbooks.